# ReactJS fetch() api call returning null or empty array

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am trying to fetch posts from wordpress RESTapi-v2 in react component.The api supplies data in json format.But fetch response in Reactjs is returning null array of posts

### below is the code

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      posts: ''
    }
    this.fetchposts = this.fetchposts.bind(this);

  }
  fetchposts(){
    fetch("http://smashingdevs.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/")
      .then( 
            (result)=> {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                posts: result,
              });
            }
         );
      console.log(this.state.posts);

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello  there</h2>
        <button onClick={this.fetchposts}>
          fetch posts
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this request requires no authentication you can check it form http://smashingdevs.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/.

How can i debug this? is there anyway to see what posts are being fetched in console?

Comment: your console is at wrong place

Answer (score 4):

a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) call returns a response object. If you need json you must first parse it.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          posts: myJson,
        });
        console.log(myJson);
    });
```

If you have async/await support in your app you can actually write it in a nicer way

```
async fetchposts() {
  let response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
  let json = await response.json();

  // do whatever
}
```

Another piece of advise: wrap your fetch call in a try catch and check for any errors that might occurr.

Answer (score 1):

The fetch api specifies that you need to transform the response into JSON before accessing the data.

[Using Fetch Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Example:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
        console.log(myJson);
    });
```

> Here we are fetching a JSON file across the network and print it to the console. The simplest use of fetch() takes one argument — the path to the resource you want to fetch — and returns a promise containing the response (a Response object).
>
> **This is just an HTTP response of course, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method** (defined on the Body mixin, which is implemented by both the Request and Response objects.)